# Multiple instances of the same TabBarController after Modal Segue iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with one main TabBarController containing two tabs that control two different views, A & B. View A is a scrollView and View B is a TableView. When i initially load the app, the scrollview in view A is empty.

In order to add pages to my scrollView, I have set it up as follows: I go to view B and perform one modal segue to a view embedded with a navigationBar. The navigationBar only has one button, 'Cancel', which I use to dismiss the view. Otherwise, the user must click on an image an perform another modal segue to a different view. This view has no navigation bar, and has one button 'DONE', which I use to perform a modal segue back to the initial tabBarController.

Here's the problem: the page is added to the scrollView with no errors after I press 'DONE'. However, I believe I now have two instances of the same tabBarController floating around in memory. When I attempt to grab the views contained in the scrollView with a different button, it tells me that it is now empty (even though it was full during viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear).

How can I remove the initial tabBarController view or otherwise how can I segue back to the tabBarController that I have already allocated? Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do a segue back to the original view controller. Rather, you should dismiss the current view controllers animated, and show your original tabBarController.

Inside the view you were segueing back from, add:

```
tabBarController *tabs = (tabBarController*)[[self presentingViewController]presentingViewController];
tabs.selectedViewController = [tabz.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then you will have the view A appear and still use the same allocation.